# How can solve this Complex Equation?

Tags: complex-analysis

Cz :$Imaginary(z)=2$ and what shows on $W$ or $F(z)=(1-i)Z+2-3i$. While solving the denominator is $1-i^2$ that goes to zero. Anyone can solve ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, $C(z): \Im(z) = 2$ is an equation and you have another complex line $(1-i)z + 2 - 3i$ and you want their intersection? Is that right? If so, this is simply 2 linear equations in 2 variables, so just simultaneous equations.

Comment: u have the plane Imaginary (x+iy) >2 and have to show what is the locus on F(z) plane that have this equation .

Comment: Sorry i finded Im(z) >2  is y> 2 . After i stuck solving f(z) because when i transform goes z=W-2+3i/1-i and if u conjugate denominator goes 0. This type is like Z=x+iy and u show how that is mirror in W=U+iV.

Comment: So you got to find the image of the half-plane $Im(z)>2$ under the linear function $w=F(z)$?

Comment: thank you .In fact 1-i^2 is 2 and i solve it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually
$$
1-i^2 = 1-(-1)=2.
$$